# Can you cast an object to one that implements an interface? (JAVA)

Tags: java, user-interface, casting, object

Can you cast an object to one that implements an interface? Right now, I'm building a GUI, and I don't want to rewrite the Confirm/Cancel code (A confirmation pop-up) over and over again.

So, what I'm trying to do is write a class that gets passed *the class* it's used in and tells *the class* whether or not the user pressed Confirm or Cancel. *The class* always implements a certain interface.

Code:

```
class ConfirmFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JButton confirm = new JButton("Confirm");
    JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    Object o;

    public ConfirmFrame(Object o)
    {
        // Irrelevant code here
        add(confirm);
        add(cancel);
        this.o = (/*What goes here?*/)o;
    }

    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent evt)
    {
        o.actionPerformed(evt);
    }
}
```

I realize that I'm probably over-complicating things, but now that I've run across this, I really want to know if you can cast an object to another object that implements a certain interface.

Comment: you should use the Interface all the classes implement instead of Object, or even better use Generics instead of Object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast objects either up or down the type hierarchy; sometimes this is safe, and sometimes it isn't. If you attempt to cast a variable to an incompatible type (i.e. try to convince the compiler it's something it's not), you'll get a runtime exception (i.e. error). Going to a more general type (like changing an `ActionListener` into an `Object`) is called upcasting, and is always safe, assuming the class you're casting to is one of the ancestors of your current class (and `Object` is an ancestor of everything in Java). Going to a more specific type (like casting from `ActionListener` to `MySpecialActionListener`) only works if your object actually **is** an instance of the more specific type.

So, in your case, it sounds like what you're trying to do is say that ConfirmFrame implements the interface ActionListener. I assume that that interface includes:

```
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent evt);
```

And then here, in your implementation of that virtual method, you want to delegate the evt to whatever object `o` was passed into the constructor. The problem here is that `Object` doesn't have a method called `actionPerformed`; only a more specialized class (in this case, an implementation of `ActionListener` like your `ConfirmFrame` class) would have it. So what you probably want is for that constructor to take an `ActionListener` instead of an `Object`.

```
class ConfirmFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JButton confirm = new JButton("Confirm");
    JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    ActionListener a;

    public ConfirmFrame(ActionListener a)
    {
        // Irrelevant code here
        add(confirm);
        add(cancel);
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent evt)
    {
        a.actionPerformed(evt);
    }
}
```

Of course, more explanatory variable names than "o" or "a" would probably help you (and anyone else reading this) understand why you're passing an ActionListener into another ActionListener.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can - the usual syntax for casting applies. You could even declare the parameter type as the interface rather than `Object`.

*Edit:* of course, the type of the variable also needs to be the interface or, alternatively you can cast it when calling a method on it, ie.

```
ActionPerformer o;
...
this.o = (ActionPerformer)o;
```

or

```
((ActionPerformer)this.o).actionPerformed(evt);
```

Comment: So, uh, you would do: "this.o = (ActionListener)o;"? I tried doing that earlier, but method actionPerformed() isn't found.

Comment: Ohhhhh, wait up, Fixed. The reason it couldn't find it was b/c i initialized the Object as an Object instead of as the interface. Thanks, Evgeny :D

Answer (score 0):

Example Usage of  the Above answer: :)

```
class MyFrame extends Frame{ 



         ActionListener confirmListener = new ActionListener (){

                //implementation of the ActionListener I
                   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                          if ( e.getActionCommand().equals("Cancel")){
                              // do Something
                          }
                          else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Confirm")){
                             // do Something
                         }
                   } 
         };

         ConfirmFrame confirmDialog = new ConfirmDialog(confirmListener);

         //code that uses the ConfirmFrame  goes here....

}
```